# Mix static text fields with outputFields (visually)

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

In my VF page I need to display lines containing data, some fetched from the object and some written statically like so:

```
<apex:outputField label="Raised by" value="{!$User.activeUser}"/>                
Requester Type: Commercial <br/>
Request Type: Bespoke <br/>
```

This is how it currently looks like...
[image]

How can I have the two lines of static text display in the same style like the outputfield line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags you need are these:

```
<apex:outputField label="Raised by" value="{!$User.activeUser}"/> 
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Requester Type"/>
    <apex:outputText value="Commercial"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Request Type"/>
    <apex:outputText value="Bespoke"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```